# Big memory footprint of domNode document representation

Tags: html, optimization, browser, dom-node, memory-footprint

I have some relatively small HTML document - just couple of dozens table rows, with a few columns, one of them has text type info, another contains minimalistic form with submit button, i.e. form/button in each row  of that column. Nothing special. CURL reports that my total HTML document weights approx 26 KB. However when I check document memory footprint in a Firefox browser I get this picture :

[image]

Meaning that domNode representation of whole document is **1 MB** ! This means that overhead of domNode representation of full document compared to plain HTML output size is about 40x ! Question is - What's so special about domNode type ? Why browser needs such amount of additional overhead data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your comparison is incorrect.
It's like if one asked "Why the blueprints of this car weights 1.5 kg but the car itself weights 1500 kg? Overhead is 1000x!"

HTML code is just a high-level blueprint for HTML interpreters (e. g. web browsers).
Browser parses the code and creates Document Object Model (DOM) where each node is an object and have some properties. That requires memory.

Please look at the snippet below, or even better, open Firefox console and type `document`.
You'll see a lot of stuff (even behind empty `<html></html>`).

```js
console.log(document)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0}
```

Comment: I understand this. But different manufacturers can make slightly different cars  from the same blueprint ! Similarly, different browsers can build slightly different DOM models and relying architectures from the same HTML snippet. This begs for question- Which DOM model representation is better ?, optimization, redundant memory consumption, maybe even memory leaks, etc. Hence, the question, Does Firefox really needs THAT MUCH, or can it be optimized ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas, you're right, browser engines may have slightly different internal representation of HTML document. But in general, browser engines implement HTML, CSS, JS and some other standards. So most of the properties are proposed by those standards. They cannot be omitted. I'm not a browser developer and cannot suggest how to optimize browser code. But as a webdev I can optimize my own code: minimize number of elements and attributes in HTML, minimize re-flows and re-paints in CSS, minimize time and space complexity in JS.